# Accurately and seamlessly splitting text into two UILabels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a "wrapping" like effect for text around an image that has set dimensions.

```
         ___________
........|   
........| image
label.1.|
........|___________
....................
.......label.2......
....................
....................
```

Here is the method im using right now:

```
- (NSArray *)splitString:(NSString*)str maxCharacters:(NSInteger)maxLength { //this will split the string to add to two UILabels
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    NSArray *wordArray = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSInteger numberOfWords = [wordArray count];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSInteger lengthOfNextWord = 0;

    while (index < numberOfWords) {
        NSMutableString *line = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1];
        while ((([line length] + lengthOfNextWord + 1) <= maxLength) && (index < numberOfWords)) {
            lengthOfNextWord = [[wordArray objectAtIndex:index] length];
            [line appendString:[wordArray objectAtIndex:index]];
            index++;
            if (index < numberOfWords) {
                [line appendString:@" "];
            }
        }
        [tempArray addObject:line];
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```

I give it the maxCharacters value of where I want to split the text, which is the max height of the first UILabel. This method is essentially what I want, but sometimes the last line of the first UILabel is "higher" than others leaving a gap between the first UILabel and the second UILabel.

Here is how I use the method:

```
NSArray *splitStringArray = [self splitString:eventRecord.summary maxCharacters:280];

    UILabel *firstSumValue = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    NSString *firstSumString = [splitStringArray objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize maxFirstSumSize = CGSizeMake(185.0,150.0);
    UIFont *firstSumFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12];
    CGSize firstSumStringSize = [firstSumString sizeWithFont:firstSumFont
                                     constrainedToSize:maxFirstSumSize
                                         lineBreakMode:firstSumValue.lineBreakMode];



    CGRect firstSumFrame = CGRectMake(10.0, presentedValue.frame.origin.y + presentedValue.frame.size.height, 185.0, firstSumStringSize.height);


    firstSumValue.frame = firstSumFrame;

    firstSumValue.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
    firstSumValue.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    firstSumValue.numberOfLines = 0 ;
    [self.mainScrollView addSubview:firstSumValue];



    firstSumValue.text = [splitStringArray objectAtIndex:0];


    UILabel *secondSumValue = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    NSInteger isSecond = 0;  //no
    if([splitStringArray count] > 1){
        isSecond = 1;  //yes

        NSString *secondSumString = [splitStringArray objectAtIndex:1];
        CGSize maxSecondSumSize = CGSizeMake(310.0,9999.0);
        UIFont *secondSumFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12];
        CGSize secondSumStringSize = [secondSumString sizeWithFont:secondSumFont
                                               constrainedToSize:maxSecondSumSize
                                                   lineBreakMode:secondSumValue.lineBreakMode];



        CGRect secondSumFrame = CGRectMake(10.0, firstSumValue.frame.origin.y + firstSumValue.frame.size.height, 310.0, secondSumStringSize.height);


        secondSumValue.frame = secondSumFrame;

        secondSumValue.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
        secondSumValue.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        secondSumValue.numberOfLines = 0 ;
        [self.mainScrollView addSubview:secondSumValue];


         secondSumValue.text = [splitStringArray objectAtIndex:1];


    }
```

How do I keep everything consistent and aligned properly. Perhaps, there is a better method one could recommend. Not core text because it's out of my scope of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a UIWebView instead, with the layout defined in a local HTML file.  It can save you a lot of headache rather than trying to deal with complex layouts by hand.

Comment: how would one combat the half-second loading delay with a UIWebView?